# Mysql- Is this a good optimised query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

This could be a dumb question. I have over 30M records.

```
Table 1

Column A(int) - Column B(Boolean) - Column C(int) - Column D(DateTime)
```

I will have a composite index on (A,B,C,D).

The following is the query:

```
Select * from table1 where A=12 and B!=0 ORDER BY C DESC ,D ASC.
```

Since `Order by C DESC and D ASC` is not possible . I am reverse sorting by multiplying the C with (-1) every time I insert a record.

Now the query I am trying to execute will be:

```
Select * from table1 where A=12 and B!=0 ORDER BY C ASC ,D ASC.
```

Considering two criteria in `where` clause and the `order by`, will this above query make full use of the indexing? Or is there any other better solution?

Answer (score 4):

There is a very useful SQL command, called EXPLAIN.

It does exactly that - explains how the RDBMS would approach computing the query.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am sorry but i dont have access to a mysql database at the moment. It would take a while for me to do that test. It would be great if you can let me know the theory behind how it does the job in that situation? Possibly provide some great alternatives which i am sure i dont have any idea abt.

Comment: To be quite honest, it totally depends on the setup, cardinality of the records, etc. Basically, the science and art behind query optimizer is rather delicate, and very specific to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the negatives in `C` column so the query with `ORDER BY C DESC, D ASC` can be changed to `ORDER BY C ASC, D ASC` and use this index is a good idea. If you haven't any other queries that require other orderings (`ASC, ASC` or `DESC, DESC` or `DESC, ASC` that's OK.

But I would also change the `B != 0` condition to `B = 1`. The optimizer may not be so clever to identify these as identical and may not use the index properly (or not at all).